# Put integer variable in string manually

Tags: c++, string, integer

I got a quick question for the following code

```
int main()
{
    string data;
    int x;
    cin >> x;

    if (x < 0)
    {
        data = to_string(x);
    }
    else
    {
        data = to_string(x);
    }
   return 0;
}
```

If I does not want to use `to_string(x)`, instead I want to do something manually. Is there anyway I can do that? If I use `data = x;` this obviously won't work.

ps. I doesn't want to use `atoi` either,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
int main(){
    int x;
    cin>>x;
    string s = "";     // s will represent x but with the digits reversed
    bool neg = 0;      // this flag is 1 if x is negative and 0 if positive. 
                       // we will use it to find out if we should put a "-" before the number
    if(x < 0){
        neg = 1;
        x *= -1;       // making the number positive
    }
    while(x){
        char c = '0' + x % 10;          // c represent the least significant digit of x
        s.push_back(c);                 // adding c to s             
        x /= 10;                        // removing the least significant digit of x
    }
    string ans = "";                    // ans is our resulting string
    if(neg) ans.push_back('-');         // adding a negative sign if x was negative
    for(int i=s.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)    // adding the characters of s in reverse order
        ans.push_back(s[i]);
}
```

Comment: If `std::to_string` doesn't qualify as "manually", I don't see how this would.

Comment: Sorry, I did not pay attention. I will modify my code.

Comment: What is the reason to put the digit in reversed order?

Comment: x%10 will return an integer between 0 and 9. but we need a character to represent the integer. And in the ASCII table (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) we have the sequence of digits come in sequence starting with 0 (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9). So if we add to the ASCII value of '0' an integer x between 0 and 9 we will get a character with the ASCII value representing the integer x.

Comment: x%10 returns the least significant digit of x. So 123%10 will return 3. And we are saving 3 in s[0], but in the final string 3 should be in the last index.

Answer (score 1):

This might be sufficient.

```
string convertInt(int number)
{
    if (number == 0)
        return "0";
    string temp="";
    string returnvalue="";
    while (number>0)
    {
        temp+=number%10+'0';
        number/=10;
    }
    for (int i=0;i<temp.length();i++)
        returnvalue+=temp[temp.length()-i-1];
    return returnvalue;
}
```

(I did not write this function, but found it by doing a [quick Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=convert%20int%20to%20string%20manually). The original post [is here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/7777/).)

This function works by dividing the number by 10. It takes the remainder of the division, which will always be between 0 and 9. It then "finds" the character representing that number by adding the integral value of the character `0` to it.

Next, it takes the quotient of that division, and performs the same operation again and again until the quotient is zero.

This results in a string that contains the characters representing the number, but in reverse order. The final loop reverses the string before returning it.

As chris points out in the comments below, the digits 0 through 9 are guaranteed to be in sequential order

> N3485, §2.3 [lex.charset]/3: In both the source and execution basic
>   character sets, the value of each character after 0 in the above list
>   of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous.
>   (the above list is, quite intuitively, 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9).

Here is good reading material about string manipulation: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: Not sure why the down vote. This does as the OP asked, without really calling another function to accomplish the job.

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but can see why it was.   The code assumes a particular character set (ASCII) and will not work with others.   There are much less cryptic ways to do the job as well.

Comment: Rather than giving a warning that it won't work with other character sets while using a number that is hard to understand unless you know '0' is 48 in ASCII, why not just use `'0'`? `'0'` through `'9'` are guaranteed to be consecutive in the character set, `'0'` conveys meaning a lot better, and now the code works portably (not that depending on ASCII really makes a difference for 99% of code).

Comment: It's possible the other digits aren't simply the next 9 characters, and it could still fail.

Comment: @Steve, Sorry, edited my comment, but they are indeed. Even if they weren't, you get the benefit of more readability with that same assumption, and no more '0' being 48 assumption.

Comment: Can you point out a reference? That would be a good link to have in the answer.

Comment: @Steve, Sure, N3485, §2.3 [lex.charset]/3: *In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after 0 in the
above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous.* (the above list is, quite intuitively, *0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9*).

Answer (score 0):

Formatting an integer manually in any number base isn't hard. E.g. in base 10:

```
void print(int n)
{
    if (n == 0) { std::cout << '0'; return; }
    if (n < 0) { std::cout << '-'; n = -n; }

    std::string buf;
    while (n != 0) { buf += '0' + n % 10; n /= 10; }
    for (auto it = buf.rbegin(); it != buf.rend(); ++it)
        std::cout << *it;
}
```

If your number base is larger than ten, you'll have to provide a suitable alphabet and use `n % base` to enumerate the desired digit.

If you want to avoid reallocations, you can reserve capacity in the string, and you can compute the required capacity by taking a suitable logarithm of `n`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really must extract the digits yourself

```
std::string manual_convert(int value)
{
    if (x < 0)
       return std::string("-") + manual_convert(-x);   // handle negative values (except potentially INT_MIN)
    else if (x == 0)
       return "0";

    std::string retval;
    while (x > 0)
    {
         char digit = x%10 + '0';     // extract the proverbial digit
         retval.append(1, digit);
         x /= 10;                     // drop the digit, and prepare for next one
    }

    std::reverse(retval.begin(), retval.end());   // loop above extracted digits in reverse order
    return retval;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two easy ways:

```
#include <sstream>
string intToString(int x)
{
   stringstream stream;
   stream << x;
   return stream.str();
}
```

Or if you using boost library

```
string str = lexical_cast<string>(x)
```